# Grouping row by specified column from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this array

```
   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.4
            [StokOpnameTransNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21
            [ItemCode] => BBG150400005
            [ItemName] => BIG BAG
            [OriginalPrice] => 289900.00
            [Price] => 289900.00
            [QtyBegining] => 0
            [QtyIn] => 4
            [QtySales] => 0
            [QtyMutasi] => 0
            [QtyStock] => 4
            [QtyOpname] => 0
            [QtyAdjust] => -4
            [TotalAdjust] => -1159600.00
            [rak] => 
            [line] => 
            [TransDate] => 2017-03-31 10:46:00.000
            [CustomerCode] => K-LFMCD2
            [CreatedBy] => 1208496.
            [Remark] => re
            [Remark2] => re
            [SOTerakhir] => 
            [TglSoTerakhir] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.5
            [StokOpnameTransNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21
            [ItemCode] => BBG150500063
            [ItemName] => BIG BAG
            [OriginalPrice] => 479900.00
            [Price] => 479900.00
            [QtyBegining] => 0
            [QtyIn] => 0
            [QtySales] => 0
            [QtyMutasi] => 0
            [QtyStock] => 0
            [QtyOpname] => 1
            [QtyAdjust] => 0
            [TotalAdjust] => .00
            [rak] => SS
            [line] => SS
            [TransDate] => 2017-03-31 10:46:00.000
            [CustomerCode] => K-LFMCD2
            [CreatedBy] => 1208496.
            [Remark] => re
            [Remark2] => re
            [SOTerakhir] => 
            [TglSoTerakhir] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.5
            [StokOpnameTransNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21
            [ItemCode] => BBG150500063
            [ItemName] => BIG BAG
            [OriginalPrice] => 479900.00
            [Price] => 479900.00
            [QtyBegining] => 0
            [QtyIn] => 1
            [QtySales] => 0
            [QtyMutasi] => 0
            [QtyStock] => 1
            [QtyOpname] => 0
            [QtyAdjust] => 0
            [TotalAdjust] => .00
            [rak] => 
            [line] => 
            [TransDate] => 2017-03-31 10:46:00.000
            [CustomerCode] => K-LFMCD2
            [CreatedBy] => 1208496.
            [Remark] => re
            [Remark2] => re
            [SOTerakhir] => 
            [TglSoTerakhir] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.6
            [StokOpnameTransNo] => OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21
            [ItemCode] => BBG150500081
            [ItemName] => BIG BAG
            [OriginalPrice] => 229900.00
            [Price] => 229900.00
            [QtyBegining] => 0
            [QtyIn] => 0
            [QtySales] => 0
            [QtyMutasi] => 0
            [QtyStock] => 0
            [QtyOpname] => 1
            [QtyAdjust] => 0
            [TotalAdjust] => .00
            [rak] => SS
            [line] => SS
            [TransDate] => 2017-03-31 10:46:00.000
            [CustomerCode] => K-LFMCD2
            [CreatedBy] => 1208496.
            [Remark] => re
            [Remark2] => re
            [SOTerakhir] => 
            [TglSoTerakhir] => 
        )

)
```

My array(s) comming from the query result . Then i'm trying to put it to HTML Table so i try this way.

```
<table class="table ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>ItemCode</th>
                            <th>ItemName</th>
                            <th>TransNo</th>
                            <th>Original Price</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                             <th>QtyBeginning</th>
                            <th>QtyIn</th>
                            <th>QtySales</th>
                            <th>QtyMutasi</th>
                            <th>QtyStock</th>
                            <th>QtyOpname</th>
                            <th>QtyAdjust</th>
                            <th>TotalAdjust</th>
                            <th>Rak</th>
                            <th>Line</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> <?php $x=0; foreach ($datadetail as $data) { $x++;?>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><?=$x;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->ItemCode;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->ItemName;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->StokOpnameTransNo;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->OriginalPrice;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->Price;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtyBegining;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtyIn;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtySales;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtyMutasi;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtyStock;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtyOpname;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->QtyAdjust;?></td>
                                    <td><?=currency($data->TotalAdjust);?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->rak;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$data->line;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?> 

                    </tbody>

            </table>
```

the result is just a simple table like this. There is no problem when showing my table . But, I want to change the result(in HTML) to something like this

[image]

it just like grouping by `ItemCode`. SO after every itemcode I want to sum `QtyBeginning,QtyIn,QtyOut etc`.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know your table structure but in my opinion you should be able to organize your data from your db

either way i try to show you a way how to do it (a fulltestscript)

TestData:

```
$arrTestData = [];

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.4";
$obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
$obj->ItemCode = "BBG150400005";
$obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
$obj->OriginalPrice = "289900.00";
$obj->Price = "289900.00";
$obj->QtyBegining = "0";
$obj->QtyIn = "4";
$obj->QtySales = "0";
$obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
$obj->QtyStock = "4";
$obj->QtyOpname = "2";
$obj->QtyAdjust = "-4";
$obj->TotalAdjust = "-1159600.00";
$obj->rak = "";
$obj->line = "";
$obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
$obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
$obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
$obj->Remark = "re";
$obj->Remark2 = "re";
$obj->SOTerakhir = "";
$obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
$arrTestData[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.4";
$obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
$obj->ItemCode = "BBG150400005";
$obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
$obj->OriginalPrice = "289900.00";
$obj->Price = "289900.00";
$obj->QtyBegining = "0";
$obj->QtyIn = "2";
$obj->QtySales = "0";
$obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
$obj->QtyStock = "4";
$obj->QtyOpname = "4";
$obj->QtyAdjust = "-4";
$obj->TotalAdjust = "-1159600.00";
$obj->rak = "";
$obj->line = "";
$obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
$obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
$obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
$obj->Remark = "re";
$obj->Remark2 = "re";
$obj->SOTerakhir = "";
$obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
$arrTestData[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.5";
$obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
$obj->ItemCode = "BBG150500063";
$obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
$obj->OriginalPrice = "479900.00";
$obj->Price = "479900.00";
$obj->QtyBegining = "0";
$obj->QtyIn = "0";
$obj->QtySales = "0";
$obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
$obj->QtyStock = "0";
$obj->QtyOpname = "1";
$obj->QtyAdjust = "0";
$obj->TotalAdjust = ".00";
$obj->rak = "SS";
$obj->line = "SS";
$obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
$obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
$obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
$obj->Remark = "re";
$obj->Remark2 = "re";
$obj->SOTerakhir = "";
$obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
$arrTestData[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.5";
$obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
$obj->ItemCode = "BBG150500063";
$obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
$obj->OriginalPrice = "479900.00";
$obj->Price = "479900.00";
$obj->QtyBegining = "0";
$obj->QtyIn = "1";
$obj->QtySales = "0";
$obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
$obj->QtyStock = "1";
$obj->QtyOpname = "0";
$obj->QtyAdjust = "0";
$obj->TotalAdjust = ".00";
$obj->rak = "";
$obj->line = "";
$obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
$obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
$obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
$obj->Remark = "re";
$obj->Remark2 = "re";
$obj->SOTerakhir = "";
$obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
$arrTestData[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.6";
$obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
$obj->ItemCode = "BBG150500081";
$obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
$obj->OriginalPrice = "229900.00";
$obj->Price = "229900.00";
$obj->QtyBegining = "0";
$obj->QtyIn = "0";
$obj->QtySales = "0";
$obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
$obj->QtyStock = "0";
$obj->QtyOpname = "1";
$obj->QtyAdjust = "0";
$obj->TotalAdjust = ".00";
$obj->rak = "SS";
$obj->line = "SS";
$obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
$obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
$obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
$obj->Remark = "re";
$obj->Remark2 = "re";
$obj->SOTerakhir = "";
$obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
$arrTestData[] = $obj;
```

You need an Item Collection or something like that which holds and structurize your data

```
class ItemCollection extends ArrayObject
{

    private $strCollectionCode;
    private $strCollectionName;

    public function addItem($objItem)
    {
        $this->strCollectionCode = $objItem->ItemCode;
        $this->strCollectionName = $objItem->ItemName;
        $this->append($objItem);
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        return $this->$key;
    }

    public function getSummaries($strKey)
    {
        $floatNumber = 0;
        foreach($this AS $objItem)
        {
            $floatNumber += floatval($objItem->$strKey);
        }
        return $floatNumber;
    }
}
```

And a Wrapper should contain this Collections

```
class ItemCollectionWrapper
{
    private $arrCollections = array();

    public function __construct($arrData = false)
    {
        if (is_array($arrData))
        {
            $this->addItemsFromArray($arrData);
        }
    }

    public function addItem($objItem)
    {
        if (isset($this->arrCollections[$objItem->ItemCode]))
        {
            $objCollection = $this->arrCollections[$objItem->ItemCode];
        }
        else
        {
            $objCollection = new ItemCollection();
            $this->arrCollections[$objItem->ItemCode] = $objCollection;
        }

        $objCollection->addItem($objItem);
    }

    public function addItemsFromArray($arrData)
    {
        foreach($arrData AS $obj)
        {
            $this->addItem($obj);
        }
    }

    public function getCollections()
    {
        return $this->arrCollections;
    }
}
```

and finally our view

```
<?php
    $obj = new ItemCollectionWrapper($arrTestData);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang=en> 
<head> 
    <meta charset=utf-8> 
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible> 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    td.summaries 
    {
        background:#c6c600;
    }
</style>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>ItemCode</th>
        <th>ItemName</th>
        <th>TransNo</th>
        <th>Original Price</th>
        <th>Price</th>
         <th>QtyBeginning</th>
        <th>QtyIn</th>
        <th>QtySales</th>
        <th>QtyMutasi</th>
        <th>QtyStock</th>
        <th>QtyOpname</th>
        <th>QtyAdjust</th>
        <th>TotalAdjust</th>
        <th>Rak</th>
        <th>Line</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach($obj->getCollections() AS $objCollection)
{
    $number = 1;
?>
    <?php
    foreach($objCollection AS $key => $objItem) :
    ?>
     <tr>
        <?php
        if ($key == 0)  :
        ?>
        <td rowspan="<?=$objCollection->count();?>"><?=$number;?></td>
        <td rowspan="<?=$objCollection->count();?>"><?=$objCollection->get("strCollectionCode");?></td>
        <td rowspan="<?=$objCollection->count();?>"><?=$objCollection->get("strCollectionName");?></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td><?=$objItem->StokOpnameTransNo;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->OriginalPrice;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->Price;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtyBegining;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtyIn;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtySales;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtyMutasi;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtyStock;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtyOpname;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->QtyAdjust;?></td>
        <td><?=($objItem->TotalAdjust);?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->rak;?></td>
        <td><?=$objItem->line;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtyBegining");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtyIn");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtySales");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtyMutasi");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtyStock");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtyOpname");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("QtyAdjust");?></td>
        <td class="summaries"><?=$objCollection->getSummaries("TotalAdjust");?></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $number++;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope it helps - if you study this code - you should be able to extend it in whatever way you like.

btw: You can put the classes ItemCollectionWrapper and ItemCollection below your model Code
if you dont know how to do that - show me your model and your controller and i'll show you.

Answer (score 0):

First I working for improving my English.

Second: I have a solution for this issue, try this I hope some help. 
Idea -> I try to compare Item code from array return by SQL (You mutch sort **Itemcode** by asc order.

then try thís code 
php Code

```
<?php 
class Item{
    protected $data;

    public function _construct($itemData){
        $_arr = array(
            'QtyBegining'   => $itemData->QtyBegining,
            'QtyIn'         => $itemData->QtyIn,
            'QtySales'      => $itemData->QtySales,
            'QtyStock'      => $itemData->QtyStock,
            'QtyOpname'     => $itemData->QtyOpname,
            'QtyAdjust'     => $itemData->QtyAdjust,
            'TotalAdjust'   => $itemData->TotalAdjust
        )
        $this->data = $_arr;
    }

    public function setData($key, $value){
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getData($key){
        return $this->data[$key];
    }


    public $QtyBegining;
    public $QtyIn;
    public $QtySales;
    public $QtyStock;
    public $QtyOpname;
    public $QtyAdjust;
    public $TotalAdjust;
}
?>
```

---

```
<tbody>
    <?php $x=0;
    $revertItemcode = null; 
    $revertSum = null;
    foreach ($datadetail as $data) 
    { 
        $hasNewItemcode = false;
        if($revertItemcode == null) {

            //If first Item
            $revertItemcode = $data->ItemCode;

            //Set revert itemcode to new Itemcode
            $revertSum = new Item($data);
        }else{
            //If have not equa with revert item code
            if($revertItemcode != $data->ItemCode;){
                $hasNewItemcode = true;
            }
        }

        //Sum with revert item if equa Itemcode
        if(!$hasNewItemcode){

            $revertSum->setData('QtyBegining', $revertSum->getData('QtyBegining') + $data->QtyBegining);

            $revertSum->setData('QtyIn', $revertSum->getData('QtyIn') + $data->QtyIn);

            $revertSum->setData('QtySales', $revertSum->getData('QtySales') + $data->QtySales);

            $revertSum->setData('QtyStock', $revertSum->getData('QtyStock') + $data->QtyStock);

            $revertSum->setData('QtyOpname', $revertSum->getData('QtyOpname') + $data->QtyOpname);

            $revertSum->setData('QtyAdjust', $revertSum->getData('QtyAdjust') + $data->QtyAdjust);

            $revertSum->setData('TotalAdjust', $revertSum->getData('revertSum') + $data->TotalAdjust);            
        }
        $x++;
    ?>  
        <?php
        //Echo sumary row with revert item code. 
        if($hasNewItemcode):?>
        <tr class="sumary-item-code">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtyBegining');?></td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtyIn');?></td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtySales');?></td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtyMutasi');?></td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtyStock');?></td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtyOpname');?></td>
            <td><?=$revertSum->getData('QtyAdjust');?></td>
            <td><?=currency($revertSum->getData('TotalAdjust'));?></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        //Set revert itemcode to new Itemcode
        $revertSum = new Item($data);
        ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$x;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->ItemCode;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->ItemName;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->StokOpnameTransNo;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->OriginalPrice;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->Price;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtyBegining;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtyIn;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtySales;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtyMutasi;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtyStock;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtyOpname;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->QtyAdjust;?></td>
            <td><?=currency($data->TotalAdjust);?></td>
            <td><?=$data->rak;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->line;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?> 

</tbody>
```

Comment: sorry, i'm bit confuse. I'm using codeigniter. Where should i put Class Item ?

Comment: Anywhere you can, I don't know Codeigniter much, but I think you can define class from model or helper

Answer (score 0):

@YVS1102
First you need to arrange your data (associative array) so that you can loop as per your requirement.

```
foreach($datadetail  as $k=>$v){
        $result[$v->ItemCode][] = $v;
    }
```

Now in view you can loop as below

```
$i=0;
    foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        $i++; 
        $j= $qtyBegining = $qtyIn = $qtySale = $qtyMutasi = $qtyStock = $qtyOpname = $qtAdjust = $totalAdjust = 0;
        /** we can use foreach also however we need to calculate the Qty so we will use for **/           

        for($k=0;$k<=(count($value));$k++ ){
             <tr>
                <?php if($j==0){?>
                   <td rowspan="<?php echo count($value)+1;?>"><?php echo $i;?></td>    
                   <td rowspan="<?php echo count($value)+1;?>"><?php echo $value[$k]->ItemCode;?></td>    
                   <td rowspan="<?php echo count($value)+1;?>"><?php echo $value[$k]->ItemName;?></td>    
                <?php }?>  
                   <?php if(isset($value[$k]) && !empty($value[$k])){
                      $qtyBegining = $qtyBegining + $value[$k]->QtyBegining;
                      $qtyIn = $qtyIn + $value[$k]->QtyIn;
                      $qtySale = $qtySale + $value[$k]->QtySales;
                      $qtyMutasi = $qtyMutasi + $value[$k]->QtyMutasi;
                      $qtyStock = $qtyStock + $value[$k]->QtyStock;
                      $qtyOpname = $qtyOpname + $value[$k]->QtyOpname;
                      $qtAdjust = $qtAdjust + $value[$k]->QtyAdjust;
                      $totalAdjust = $totalAdjust + $value[$k]->TotalAdjust;
                   }?>
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  ' ' : $value[$k]->StokOpnameTransNo ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  ' ' : $value[$k]->OriginalPrice ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  ' ' : $value[$k]->Price ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtyBegining : $value[$k]->QtyBegining ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtyIn : $value[$k]->QtyIn ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtySale : $value[$k]->QtySales ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtyMutasi : $value[$k]->QtyMutasi ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtyStock : $value[$k]->QtyStock ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtyOpname : $value[$k]->QtyOpname ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $qtAdjust : $value[$k]->QtyAdjust ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  $totalAdjust : currency($value[$k]->TotalAdjust) ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  ' ' : $value[$k]->rak ;?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo ($k == count($value) ?  ' ' : $value[$k]->line ;?></td> 

            </tr>
            $j++;
           }
        }
```

You don't need to create new class in above method.

Comment: Yep, I agree that you don't need to create a new class, but with a class holding the data you have a cleaner code. To me, this works but looks "ugly".

Comment: As per my understanding @YVS1102 is fetching data from database by codeigniter active records (data is already in object format). We are just saving it into array and loop the array into view. However in new class method we are trying to assign same data again to another class objects.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But having that in a new class allows you give the format to the number easily, and set the empty values to be returned easily. And you keep an uniform format of your data in all your application, just in case you want to show that again in other view (you won't have to write and remember all the functions used per row).

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data: Thanks to @sintakonte for Test data

```
    $arrTestData = [];

    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.4";
    $obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
    $obj->ItemCode = "BBG150400005";
    $obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
    $obj->OriginalPrice = "289900.00";
    $obj->Price = "289900.00";
    $obj->QtyBegining = "0";
    $obj->QtyIn = "4";
    $obj->QtySales = "0";
    $obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
    $obj->QtyStock = "4";
    $obj->QtyOpname = "2";
    $obj->QtyAdjust = "-4";
    $obj->TotalAdjust = "-1159600.00";
    $obj->rak = "";
    $obj->line = "";
    $obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
    $obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
    $obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
    $obj->Remark = "re";
    $obj->Remark2 = "re";
    $obj->SOTerakhir = "";
    $obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
    $arrTestData[] = $obj;

    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.4";
    $obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
    $obj->ItemCode = "BBG150400005";
    $obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
    $obj->OriginalPrice = "289900.00";
    $obj->Price = "289900.00";
    $obj->QtyBegining = "0";
    $obj->QtyIn = "2";
    $obj->QtySales = "0";
    $obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
    $obj->QtyStock = "4";
    $obj->QtyOpname = "4";
    $obj->QtyAdjust = "-4";
    $obj->TotalAdjust = "-1159600.00";
    $obj->rak = "";
    $obj->line = "";
    $obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
    $obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
    $obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
    $obj->Remark = "re";
    $obj->Remark2 = "re";
    $obj->SOTerakhir = "";
    $obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
    $arrTestData[] = $obj;

    $obj = new stdClass();

    $obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.5";
    $obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
    $obj->ItemCode = "BBG150500063";
    $obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
    $obj->OriginalPrice = "479900.00";
    $obj->Price = "479900.00";
    $obj->QtyBegining = "0";
    $obj->QtyIn = "0";
    $obj->QtySales = "0";
    $obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
    $obj->QtyStock = "0";
    $obj->QtyOpname = "1";
    $obj->QtyAdjust = "0";
    $obj->TotalAdjust = ".00";
    $obj->rak = "SS";
    $obj->line = "SS";
    $obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
    $obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
    $obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
    $obj->Remark = "re";
    $obj->Remark2 = "re";
    $obj->SOTerakhir = "";
    $obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
    $arrTestData[] = $obj;

    $obj = new stdClass();

    $obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.5";
    $obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
    $obj->ItemCode = "BBG150500063";
    $obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
    $obj->OriginalPrice = "479900.00";
    $obj->Price = "479900.00";
    $obj->QtyBegining = "0";
    $obj->QtyIn = "1";
    $obj->QtySales = "0";
    $obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
    $obj->QtyStock = "1";
    $obj->QtyOpname = "0";
    $obj->QtyAdjust = "0";
    $obj->TotalAdjust = ".00";
    $obj->rak = "";
    $obj->line = "";
    $obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
    $obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
    $obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
    $obj->Remark = "re";
    $obj->Remark2 = "re";
    $obj->SOTerakhir = "";
    $obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
    $arrTestData[] = $obj;

    $obj = new stdClass();

    $obj->TransactionNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21.6";
    $obj->StokOpnameTransNo = "OPM-EC-K-LFMCD2-21";
    $obj->ItemCode = "BBG150500081";
    $obj->ItemName = "BIG BAG";
    $obj->OriginalPrice = "229900.00";
    $obj->Price = "229900.00";
    $obj->QtyBegining = "0";
    $obj->QtyIn = "0";
    $obj->QtySales = "0";
    $obj->QtyMutasi = "0";
    $obj->QtyStock = "0";
    $obj->QtyOpname = "1";
    $obj->QtyAdjust = "0";
    $obj->TotalAdjust = ".00";
    $obj->rak = "SS";
    $obj->line = "SS";
    $obj->TransDate = "2017-03-31 10:46:00.000";
    $obj->CustomerCode = "K-LFMCD2";
    $obj->CreatedBy = "1208496.";
    $obj->Remark = "re";
    $obj->Remark2 = "re";
    $obj->SOTerakhir = "";
    $obj->TglSoTerakhir = "";
    $arrTestData[] = $obj;
```

Now, create another array whose key is itemcode, or I can say filter data group by itemcode

```
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($arrTestData as $data){
        $newArr[$data->ItemCode][] = $data;
    }
```

Now, display the result data:

```
    echo '<table border="2">
                <tr>
                    <td>item code</td>
                    <td>item name</td>
                    <td>QtyBegining</td>
                    <td>QtyIn</td>
                    <td>QtySales</td>
                    <td>QtyMutasi</td>
                    <td>QtyStock</td>
                    <td>QtyOpname</td>
                    <td>QtyAdjust</td>
                    <td>TotalAdjust</td>
                </tr>';  //add others columns as required
    foreach ($newArr as $key => $item){
        $QtyBegining = $QtyIn = $QtySales = $QtyMutasi = $QtyStock = $QtyOpname = $QtyAdjust = $TotalAdjust = 0; // to store sum of each field itemcode wise
        for($i=0; $i<count($item); $i++){
            echo '<tr>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->ItemCode.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->ItemName.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtyBegining.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtyIn.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtySales.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtyMutasi.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtyStock.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtyOpname.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->QtyAdjust.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$item[$i]->TotalAdjust.'</td>'
                    . '</tr>';
            $QtyBegining += $item[$i]->QtyBegining;
            $QtyIn += $item[$i]->QtyIn;
            $QtySales += $item[$i]->QtySales;
            $QtyMutasi += $item[$i]->QtyMutasi;
            $QtyStock += $item[$i]->QtyStock;
            $QtyOpname += $item[$i]->QtyOpname;
            $QtyAdjust += $item[$i]->QtyAdjust;
            $TotalAdjust += $item[$i]->TotalAdjust;        
        } // end for loop
        //now display the sum of each field, note: add empty td as many required
        echo '<tr>'
            . '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
                    . '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtyBegining.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtyIn.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtySales.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtyMutasi.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtyStock.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtyOpname.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$QtyAdjust.'</td>'
                    . '<td>'.$TotalAdjust.'</td>'
                    . '</tr>';
    }  //end foreach loop
    echo '</table>';
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

recursive loop with key and values is the best way to print your array to your desired table format.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
<?php $x=0; foreach ($datadetail as $data) { $x++;
$value= $data->QtyBeginning + $data->QtyIn + $data->QtyOut;

?>
                             <tr>
                                <td><?=$x;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->ItemCode;?></td>
                                <td><?=$value;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->ItemName;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->StokOpnameTransNo;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->OriginalPrice;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->Price;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtyBegining;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtyIn;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtySales;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtyMutasi;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtyStock;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtyOpname;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->QtyAdjust;?></td>
                                <td><?=currency($data->TotalAdjust);?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->rak;?></td>
                                <td><?=$data->line;?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
```